# Excluding an element from a dictionary

Tags: python, django

I was asked to change code that I maintain (but didn't write) for a learning management system that previously listed an examed course both under examed courses and other courses and now my task was to exclude the examed course from other courses.

The following is the bugfix that I would like you to review:

```
    for term in subscriptions_courses:
        for course in subscriptions_courses.get(term):
            for examed in examed_courses:
                if examed.context.name.encode('utf-8') == course.encode('utf-8'):
                    # Exclude this course since it is already examed
                    del subscriptions_courses.get(term)[course]
```

The code in a larger context is in the view for a Django project:

```
@login_required
def my_settings(request, username=None):
    if username:
        if request.is_superuser:
            user = _get_user_or_404(username)
        else:
            if username != str(request.user.id) and username != request.user.username:
                raise Http404
            return redirect('my_subscriptions')
    else:
        user = request.user

    profile = _get_profile(user)

    if request.POST:
        if request.POST.get('unsub_examed') == 'true':
            remove_all_finished_course_subscriptions(request, profile)
            return redirect('my_settings')

        profile.default_schema_view = request.POST.get('default_schema_view')
        profile.save()
        profile.invalidate_cache()

        _update_subscriptions(request, profile)
        Notices.put(request, _(u"Dina inställningar har sparats."))
        if user != request.user:
            return redirect('my_subscriptions', username=user.username)
        return redirect('my_settings')
    else:
        optional_external_codes = _external_code_choices(profile)
        grouped_subscriptions = profile.get_grouped_subscriptions()
        examed_courses = [course for course in _subscribed(Course, profile) if
                          profile.studokstatus.get(course.course_code) == 'exam']
        subscriptions_courses = grouped_subscriptions.get(u'course', {})

        # begin bugfix
        for term in subscriptions_courses:
            for course in subscriptions_courses.get(term):
                for examed in examed_courses:
                    if examed.context.name.encode('utf-8') == course.encode('utf-8'):
                        # Exclude this course since it is already examed
                        del subscriptions_courses.get(term)[course]
        # end bugfix

        help_programmes = _(u"Specifika inställningar för programwebbar du prenumererar på.")
        help_courses = _(u'Specifika inställningar för kurswebbar du prenumererar på.')
        help_groups = _(u'Specifika inställningar för gruppwebbar du prenumererar på.')

        programs = programs_for(user)
        suggested_student_groups = suggest_student_groups_as_string(programs, optional_external_codes)

        referer = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '')
        section = request.GET.getlist('section', '')

        default_schema_view = profile.default_schema_view if profile.default_schema_view else 'compact'
        default_schema_view = request.GET.get('output_format') if request.GET.get('output_format') else default_schema_view

        return render(request, "users/my_settings.html", {
            'notice_message': Notices.pop(request),
            'profile_user': user,
            'profile': profile,
            'context': profile.get_home_context(),
            'heading': _(u'Mina inställningar prenumerationer'),
            'notify_by_mail': profile.notify_by_mail,
            'subscriptions_programs': grouped_subscriptions.get(u'program', {}),
            'subscriptions_courses': subscriptions_courses,
            'subscriptions_groups': grouped_subscriptions.get(u'organic_group', {}),
            'external_codes': profile.get_external_codes(),
            'optional_external_codes': optional_external_codes,
            'default': profile.get_default_subscription_notification(),
            'course_verbose_name_plural': Course.type_name_plural(),
            'program_verbose_name_plural': Program.type_name_plural(),
            'in_personal_context': True,
            'calendar_url': profile.get_calendar_export_url(),
            'current_term': str(YearSemester()),
            'referer': referer,
            'open_schedule_expander': referer.endswith('/social/home/calendar/') or 'schedule' in section,
            'open_courses_expander': 'courses' in section,
            'open_programmes_expander': 'programmes' in section,
            'open_groups_expander': 'groups' in section,
            'open_notifications_expander': 'notifications' in section,
            'help_programmes': help_programmes,
            'help_courses': help_courses,
            'help_groups': help_groups,
            'title_programmes': _(u'Program'),
            'title_courses': _(u'Kurser'),
            'title_groups': _(u'Grupper'),
            'suggested_student_groups': suggested_student_groups,
            'examed_courses': examed_courses,
            'default_schema_view': default_schema_view,
        })
```

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying something you're currently iterating over isn't the best
idea, as in, don't do that.  Edit: Then again, I had assumed this code
works.  There should be a `RuntimeError` actually.  In any case I'd
prefer a solution without the `list` added around the values in
question.

So I assume here that `examed_courses` is a `list` with course objects,
`subscriptions_courses` is a `dict` mapping `term`/strings to another
`dict` mapping `course`/strings to *something*.

First I'd move some things around and five them names, then also add a
`break` to exit early if there was a match.  Then, since you're only
using `term` once, also iterate over the values of
`subscriptions_courses`, not the keys:

```
for courses in subscriptions_courses.itervalues():
    for course_name in list(courses):
        encoded = course_name.encode('utf-8')
        for examed in examed_courses:
            if examed.context.name.encode('utf-8') == encoded:
                # Exclude this course since it is already examed
                del courses[course_name]
                break
```

Now, since the examed_courses don't change, I'd also precompute the set
that the course names are checked against:

```
seen = set(examed.context.name.encode('utf-8') for examed in examed_courses)

for courses in subscriptions_courses.itervalues():
    for course_name in list(courses):
        if course_name.encode('utf-8') in seen:
            # Exclude this course since it is already examed
            del courses[course_name]
            break
```

N.b. the function is quite large, I'd suggest to split into more
manageable pieces at some point, e.g. separate POST/GET behaviour or so.

One other suggestion:  The fragment `x = foo if foo else bar` is a bit
more compact written as `x = foo or bar`.  `foo` is returned if it's
true, same as `foo or ...`, otherwise `bar` is returned if `foo` is not
true, same as `... or bar`.

Comment: It might be worth explaining that use of `or` as it can be confusing to people.

Comment: This is the way I would do it as well.   If ever the need to remove similar courses (e.g. not just .name = course_name ...) then you would remove the 'break' and continue to iterate over the list of courses and remove those that match (embellish the if...).

Answer (score 1):

This is not clear comment

```
# Exclude this course since it is already examed
```

What is an examed course? Why do we only want courses that haven't been examed? Why do we have to go 4 levels deep in code blocks to check this? There's a deep hierarchy here obviously but the code doesn't seem to explain how to parse it and that makes it harder to understand as a user.

Comment: I believe it is a course that the exam was already taken and/or passed (an exam)